# mvn install build failed Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (default-war) on project studentapp: Execution defau

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

maven version
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (Red Hat 3.0.5-17)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 17.0.4.1, vendor: Amazon.com Inc.
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-amazon-corretto.x86_64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.10.130-118.517.amzn2.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

java -version
openjdk version "17.0.4.1" 2022-08-12 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-17.0.4.9.1 (build 17.0.4.1+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-17.0.4.9.1 (build 17.0.4.1+9-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.jdevs</groupId>
  <artifactId>studentapp</artifactId>
  <version>2.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
   <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>deployment</id>
            <name>Internal Releases</name>
            <url>http://10.128.0.10:8081/repository/student-rel/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>deployment</id>
            <name>Internal Snapshot Releases</name>
            <url>http://10.128.0.10:8081/repository/student-snap/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Where is a question?

Comment: Please Update Maven and used plugins in project.